# Поиск повторяющихся элементов коллекции в C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, linq, коллекции

Есть коллекция элементов, представляющих собой некоторые показания в определенный день месяца:

```
public class MyValue
{
    public int day;
    public double value;
}
```

Допустим из этих элементов собрали следующую коллекцию:

```
var myList = new List<MyValue>();
myList.Add( new MyValue() { day = 6, value = 20 } );   //6-го апреля показание равно 20
myList.Add( new MyValue() { day = 6, value = 50 } );   //Еще одно показание за 6 апреля
myList.Add( new MyValue() { day = 2, value = 15 } );   //Показание за 2 апреля
```

Никак не получается придумать, как можно скомпоновать показания за один и тот-же день следующими 2 способами:

1. Оставить только большее,
2. Просуммировать все показания за один день в один элемент;

Пишу через `foreach`, выбирая поочередно элементы списка и сравнивая со всеми другими элементами во вложенном `foreach`, но тогда во время выполнения второй задачи элемент складывается сам с собой.

Мне кажется есть более хорошие способы решить эту задачу, прошу толкнуть в нужном направлении.

Может через LINQ как-то можно?

Comment: функция `GroupBy`

Comment: у вас кстати пример не скомпилируется, `myList` это список, а вы его вместо `MyValue` хотите добавлять, да и поля приватные, а вы их в списке инициализации устанавливаете, снаружи класса это не будет работать

Comment: Изменил модификаторы в вопросе и создание списка тоже сделал как нужно

Comment: Для показаний использую `double`, `int` - это день месяца. Про противоречие, наверное плохо выразился в вопросе. Имелось ввиду что в одном случае надо выбрать только большее, в другом нужно просуммировать все показания за один день. В любом случае за один день должен остаться один элемент.

Comment: @Bald Этот код используется для построения графика статистики за месяц. По х - день месяца, по у - значение. Там есть 2 типа. Если сильно упростить, то первый - это как платежи, тоесть с утра заплатили 100, вечером 200, значит за день заплатили 300, а второй - это как показания прибора. С утра было 10, к вечеру стало 20. Значит за весь день прибор показал 20.

Comment: @Bald Сами графики как таковые абсолютно идентично выглядят, принимают на себя только коллекцию элементов и тип. Поэтому строю их одним кодом, а не разными

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для группировки можно воспользоваться функцией [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx), пример

```
var myList = new List<MyValue>();
myList.Add(new MyValue() { day = 6, value = 20 });
myList.Add(new MyValue() { day = 6, value = 50 });
myList.Add(new MyValue() { day = 2, value = 15 });

var groupped = (from my in myList
                group my.value by my.day into g
                select new MyValue
                {
                    day = g.Key,
                    value = g.Max()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Bald, я бы предположил, что это два разных запроса должны быть. для первого вполне подходит, для второго нужно просто Max на Sum заменить

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MeterReading
{
    public int Day {get;set;}
    public double Value {get; set;}

}

var results = meterReadings
        .GroupBy(x=>x.Day)
        .Select(x=> new MeterReading{ Day = x.Key, Value = x.Max(v=>v.Value) })
        .ToList();
    foreach(var r in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  {1}",r.Day, r.Value));
    }
```

что бы получить сумму значение меняем `x.Max` на `x.Sum()`
[пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EYIcQz)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = myList.GroupBy(g => g.day).Select(g => g.Sum(i => i.value));
var big = myList.GroupBy(g => g.day).Select(g => g.Max(i => i.value));
```