# Группировка объектов по массиву/списку данного объекта

Tags: c#, list

Имеется такой класс:

```
public class Song {
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public List<string> Artists {get; set;}
}
```

Ещё один класс для группы:

```
public class GroupedSongs {
    public string GroupName {get; set;}
    public List<Song> Songs {get; set;}
}
```

И данные:

```
List<Song> songs = new List<Song>() {
    new Song() {
        Title = "First song", 
        Artists = new List<string> {"Artist1", "Artist2"} 
    },
    new Song() {
        Title = "Second song", 
        Artists = new List<string> {"Artist2", "Artist3"} 
    },
    new Song() {
        Title = "Third song", 
        Artists = new List<string> {"Artist1", "Artist3"} 
    }
};
```

Каким образом можно сгруппировать список так, чтобы для каждого исполнителя была группа со списками его песен? Т. е, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
// Переменная groups должна содержать список, полученное после группировки.
List<GroupedSongs> groups = new List<GroupedSongs>() {
    new GroupedSongs() {
        GroupName = "Artist1", 
        Songs = new List<Song>() {
            new Song() {Title = "First song"},
            new Song() {Title = "Third song"} 
        }
    },
    new GroupedSongs() {
        GroupName = "Artist2", 
        Songs = new List<Song>() {
            new Song() {Title = "First song"}
            new Song() {Title = "Second song"}
        }, 
    },
    new GroupedSongs() {
        GroupName = "Artist3", 
        Songs = new List<Song>() {
            new Song() {Title = "Second song"}
            new Song() {Title = "Third song"}
        }, 
    },

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Поиск повторяющихся элементов коллекции в C#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510304/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: GroupBy не пробовали?

Comment: @VladD, а чего бы не жахнуть дубликтором? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: А чёрт его знает, тут у ТС ещё Select сверху нужен.

Comment: @Grundy: Не, подождите, там же группировка по вхождению.

Comment: @VladD, я знаю про GroupBy и могу его использовать, только если свойство, с помощью которого создаётся группа, не является массивом или списком.

Comment: @Elorucov: Угу, понял проблему. У вас каждая песня может попасть во много групп.

Comment: @VladD, да, действительно, немного отличается :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var allArtists = songs.SelectMany(s => s.Artists).Distinct();
var groups = allArtists.Select(artist =>
                 new GroupedSongs()
                 {
                     GroupName = artist,
                     Songs = songs.Where(s => s.Artists.Contains(artist)).ToList()
                 }).ToList();
```

(Можно записать в одну строку, если хотите.)

Comment: я понял, чего не хватало :-) здесь нет группировки!

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант в query-синтаксисе, с использованием `GroupBy`. Мне кажется выглядит более понятно.

```
List<GroupedSongs> groups = (from song in songs
                             from artist in song.Artists
                             group song by artist into grouppedSongs
                             select new GroupedSongs()
                             {
                                 GroupName = grouppedSongs.Key,
                                 Songs = grouppedSongs.ToList()
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Хм. `group song by artist` — ничего так :)

Comment: @VladD, ага, не знаю что на счет сложности выполнения, но по виду мне кажется более понятно что вообще происходит :-)